# What prevented empires with territory in North Africa from expanding south of the Sahara? And vice versa

Tags: trade, africa, age-of-discovery, exploration, north-africa

Almost all empires I've seen that existed north of Sahara, did not expand to the south. And the empires south of the Sahara did not expand to the north (except for post 15th century European colonialists, and the Kushites). Why is this?
[image: Roman Empire]
[image: Umayyad Caliphate]
[image: Almohad Caliphate]
[image: Songhai Empire]
[image: Mali Empire]
[image: Kanem Bornu Empire]

I understand supply lines may have been difficult to establish through Sahara interior due to lack of water, but I also know that there were several trans-Sahara trade routes going through the interior. And the corridors along the Red Sea and west Africa had sufficient water availability.

[image: Ethiopian Trade routes]
[image: Mali Trade routes]
[image: Trade route 3]

[image: Africa River map]

Comment: When you are an Empire, why would you want to expand into the big bowl of sand with no value? There are enough other targets for incorporating them into your Empire. It's a little like asking "When given a bowl of sand and a chocolate pudding, most people eat the pudding. I wonder why that is?".

Comment: "I understand supply lines may have been difficult ..." No, you obviously do not understand. The average size of a caravan is about 1000 camels... That is like orders of magnitude smaller than a military supply line or an army itself. Why would one bother to occupy a sea of sand bigger than most empire just to die in a week when facing the first fortified village which can lock the access to all the food and water in the whole area?

Comment: As a comparison, most slave trading roots were able to transport about 5-10 000ish slaves a year.

Comment: @nvoigt: the imperial answer to "you can have either A or B" is usually "I want both!".

Comment: @Samid: "the corridors along the Red Sea and west Africa had sufficient water availability." But you cannot drink salt water.

Comment: The Roman legions were expected to live off the land while on the march.  Try that in the Sahara.

Comment: @nvoight I said "south of the Sahara .. or vice versa", not "in the Sahara.

Comment: @Jan Nile river stretches from the Mediterranean (north of Sahara) to Lake Victoria (south of Sahara). Its not salt water. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/River_Nile_map.svg/260px-River_Nile_map.svg.png

Comment: @Samid But the Nile river is not the red sea. Even in Egypt it is usually two or three day trips (for a caravan) from the Red Sea, in Sudan the distance is even further.

Comment: @Jan Did somebody say the Nile is the Red Sea? But it does run in a corridor along the Red Sea, does it not? Wasn't the length of the Nile the locations of massive ancient empires and marching armies? Rome to Babylon is a longer distance than Roman Thebes to Lake victoria; I don't see how 3 days travelling is a problem when you are travelling along a river. And this is the same route in reverse used by the Kushites to invade Egypt. There also ships that could be used in the Red Sea or Atlantic.

Comment: Water alone isn't everything: Rome also didn't really get very far into modern-day Germany, despite the area definitely not lacking fresh water. Or distance, for that matter: Germany is a lot closer to Rome than Mesopotamia.

Comment: @Annatar But that doesn't really answer the question. If somebody had asked "why couldn't Rome conquer all of Germany?", I'm sure many will answer with legit factors. But if asked like this about through the Sahara, answering "it couldn't be done because Rome couldn't do it to Germany" imo is a null answer.

Comment: I don't see why this question is closed and asking to focus on one question, when only one question is posted? How do I revise this? I gave an example of an ancient empire (Kushite) that spanned across the Sahara south to north, but really I haven't seen much convincing answers as to why this couldn't be repeated in the future. For example, the answer by @Greg suggests that the supply line is insufficient for invasion, thereby completely disregarding the fact of Kushite invasion through the Sahara.

Comment: @Samid It's not supposed to be an answer, it's a comment. Please read again, I didn't say it couldn't be done because Rome couldn't do it in Germany (I mean, that's obviously silly) - I said that there are more factors to a proper answer than just (fresh) water and distance.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of question (why do empires not control the desert) features heavily in [Ibn Khaldun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Khaldun)'s famous [Muqaddimah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqaddimah). His conclusion is that those desert arreas are much less productive than other areas and the population is considerably harder to control. Life in those parts is tough and so people are also tough. In fact his observation is that desert tribes will often seize power for themselves if, or rather when, the (previous) ruling dynasty declines.

What is fascinating is that somewhat similar dynamics are at play on China's northern border. Many dynasties were not able to reach north of the Gobi desert. Those that were (e.g. Liao, Jin, Yuan, Qing) usually originated from north of the Great Wall themselves.